# ReferenceError: sap is not defined, debugger does not start in VS Code

Tags: javascript, sapui5

VS Code Version: 1.86.2 (user setup)
Electron: 27.2.3
Chromium: 118.0.5993.159
Node.js: 18.17.1
V8: 11.8.172.18-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.22631

I am trying to use the node.js debugger in vs code with a sap ui5 project and it does not start.

Debugger attached.
Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...
C:\Users...\VS Projects\Hello World\webapp\controller\HelloPanel.controller.js:1
sap.ui.define([
^

```
ReferenceError: sap is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\...\VS Projects\Hello World\webapp\controller\HelloPanel.controller.js:1:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1376:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1435:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1207:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1023:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:135:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:28:49
```

What would be the problem?

.vscode launch.json:

```
"version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [

        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Program",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",

            "skipFiles": [
                "<node_internals>/**"
            ],
            "trace": true,
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}\\webapp\\controller\\MainView.controller.js"
        }
    ]
```

index.html

```
    id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
    src="https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
    data-sap-ui-theme="sap_fiori_3"
    data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m"
    data-sap-ui-resourceroots='{
        ...
    }'
    data-sap-ui-oninit="module:sap/ui/core/ComponentSupport"
    data-sap-ui-compatVersion="edge"
    data-sap-ui-async="true"
    data-sap-ui-frameOptions="trusted"
```

ui5.yaml

```
framework:
        name: OpenUI5
        version: 1.108.0
        libraries:
          - name: sap.ui.core
          - name: sap.m
          - name: sap.ui.layout
          - name: themelib_sap_horizon

manifest.json

 "sap.ui": {
    "technology": "UI5",
...

  "sap.ui5": {
    "flexEnabled": true,
    "dependencies": {
      "minUI5Version": "1.102.0",
      "libs": {
        "sap.m": {},
        "sap.ui.core": {}
      }
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

Try another SAPUI5 version in your ui5.yaml file e.g. 1.108.4 and restart your app.
I think 1.108.0 isn't supported any longer by SAP.

You can always find currently working versions on the SAPUI5 page.

[image]

Comment: It didn't help, but thanks.